# DayNight feature auto-switches to dark mode later than it should

Tags: android

I've implemented the DayNight feature as described here:

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94

When in MODE_NIGHT_AUTO, the app switches to dark mode at nighttime but it does so about 30 minutes later than it should. For instance, sunset today was at 5:58pm. The Google Maps app auto-switched into dark mode at 6:12pm, which I feel was about the right time. But my app (and others which implement this feature such as the Materialistic app) didn't switch to dark mode until about 6:40pm. I've granted the Location permission, so that can't be the problem.

Is there any way to control this time myself, short of querying an API for sunset/sunrise times? It just seems weird that Google seemingly doesn't use its own DayNight feature for Maps.